# Unable to start the Passenger - 'analytics_log_dir' is missing

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to run Passenger on Ruby 1.9.3-p392, nginx 1.2.7 and rvm 1.19.6. I'm getting this strange error:

```
Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered 
the following error during startup: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger
logging agent: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason,
with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown error)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 
'Passenger::VariantMap::MissingKeyException'

  what():  Required key 'analytics_log_dir' is missing
[ pid=17372, timestamp=1366554425 ] Process aborted! signo=SIGABRT(6), 
reason=SI_TKILL, signal sent by PID 17372 with UID 0, backtrace available.

--------------------------------------
[ pid=17372 ] Backtrace with 12 frames:
PassengerLoggingAgent[0x4d7f5c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfcb0)[0x7f3aa684bcb0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f3aa5c9e425]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x17b)[0x7f3aa5ca1b8b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x11d)[0x7f3aa6599e2d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5ef26)[0x7f3aa6597f26]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5ef53)[0x7f3aa6597f53]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5f17e)[0x7f3aa659817e]
PassengerLoggingAgent(_ZNK9Passenger10VariantMap3getERKSsb+0x8a)[0x4a0d92]
PassengerLoggingAgent(main+0x112)[0x499a43]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f3aa5c8976d]
PassengerLoggingAgent[0x498919]
```

here's a backtrace: http://pastie.org/7682098

any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Could you please extract the relevant information in that backtrace link and paste it here?

Comment: I'm not sure what's relevant, that's why I posted the link